# Slow loading of symbols during call to CoCreateInstance in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, visual-c++-2012

In my MFC project I call `CoCreateInstance` at some point:

```
if ( SUCCEEDED( CoCreateInstance ( CLSID_DragDropHelper, NULL,
                                   CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                   IID_IDropTargetHelper,
                                  (void**) &m_piDropHelper ) ))
{
   ...
}
```

and a bit later once I'm done with the `DragDropHelper` I call `Release`:

```
m_piDropHelper->Release();
```

So far so good, everything works fine.

But during debug the very first call to this `CoCreateInstance` is painfully slow because VS is loading tons of symbols (this loading is visible in the VS Output window, see below). Subsequent calls to the same `CoCreateInstance` are fast. But when I restart de debugee, the first call to this `CoCreateInstance` is slow again.

I don't need these symbols for my purpose.

Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio from loading all these symbols.

**Partial content of Output Window during debug**

```
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsCodecs.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\TortoiseOverlays\TortoiseOverlays.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitStub32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGit32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\libgit232_tgit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\zlib132_tgit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
   <30 more similar lines>
'MyProg.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\GROOVEEX.DLL'
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\GROOVEEX.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcp90.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_51cd0a7abbe4e19b\ATL90.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\Cultures\OFFICE.ODF', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\1036\GrooveIntlResource.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyProg.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
```

Comment: Have you tried using Tools/Options/Debugging/Symbols to exclude the symbols you don't want?  There's two ways to load the symbols from that dialog.

Comment: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?413482-Where-call-CoInitialize-and-CoUninitialize-in-MFC-application

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not quite sure how the discussion thread you mention is related to my question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include/exclude symbols by using *Tools/Options/Debugging/Symbols*.

[image]

The two options for "Automatically load symbols for:" should provide what you want.